# Rolling window in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-computation

I have a dataset contains wind speed in 10 minutes interval.
I would like to group the data by month and hour, then flag the data as follow :

If the wind speed is less than `10` m/s AND the data point is in the time window together with 17 consecutive other data all less than `10` m/s.

This means a rolling time window including 18 data point (3 hours of continuous measurement).

In the following plot, all data points in the left side of `1`, are less than 10, and they are in the time window together with 17 other consecutive data below 10, that's why they all marked by a yellow flag.

the data points which has been marked by `2`, are below 10, but they are not in a time window with 17 other consecutive measurements with wind speed less than `10` m/s, therefore, they are not flagged!

[image]

My sample dataset is :

```
t= structure(list(TimeStamp = structure(c(1362047400, 1362048000, 
    1362048600, 1362049200, 1362049800, 1362050400, 1362051000, 1362051600, 
    1362052200, 1362052800, 1362053400, 1362054000, 1362054600, 1362055200, 
    1362055800, 1362056400, 1362057000, 1362057600, 1362058200, 1362058800, 
    1362059400, 1362060000, 1362060600, 1362061200, 1362061800, 1362062400, 
    1362063000, 1362063600, 1362064200, 1362064800, 1362065400, 1362066000, 
    1362066600, 1362067200, 1362067800, 1362068400, 1362069000, 1362069600, 
    1362070200, 1362070800, 1362071400, 1362072000, 1362072600, 1362073200, 
    1362073800, 1362074400, 1362075000, 1362075600, 1362076200, 1362076800, 
    1362077400, 1362078000, 1362078600, 1362079200, 1362079800, 1362080400, 
    1362081000, 1362081600, 1362082200, 1362082800, 1362083400, 1362084000, 
    1362084600, 1362085200, 1362085800, 1362086400, 1362087000, 1362087600, 
    1362088200, 1362088800, 1362089400, 1362090000, 1362090600, 1362091200, 
    1362091800, 1362092400, 1362093000, 1362093600, 1362094200, 1362094800, 
    1362095400, 1362096000, 1362096600, 1362097200, 1362097800, 1362098400, 
    1362099000, 1362099600, 1362100200, 1362100800, 1362101400, 1362102000, 
    1362102600, 1362103200, 1362103800, 1362104400, 1362105000, 1362105600, 
    1362106200, 1362106800, 1362107400, 1362108000, 1362108600, 1362109200, 
    1362109800, 1362110400, 1362111000, 1362111600, 1362112200, 1362112800, 
    1362113400, 1362114000, 1362114600, 1362115200, 1362115800, 1362116400, 
    1362117000, 1362117600, 1362118200, 1362118800, 1362119400, 1362120000, 
    1362120600, 1362121200, 1362121800, 1362122400, 1362123000, 1362123600, 
    1362124200, 1362124800, 1362125400, 1362126000, 1362126600, 1362127200, 
    1362127800, 1362128400, 1362129000, 1362129600, 1362130200, 1362130800, 
    1362131400, 1362132000, 1362132600, 1362133200, 1362133800, 1362134400, 
    1362135000, 1362135600, 1362136200, 1362136800, 1362137400, 1362138000, 
    1362138600, 1362139200, 1362139800, 1362140400, 1362141000, 1362141600, 
    1362142200, 1362142800, 1362143400, 1362144000, 1362144600, 1362145200, 
    1362145800, 1362146400, 1362147000, 1362147600, 1362148200, 1362148800, 
    1362149400, 1362150000, 1362150600, 1362151200, 1362151800, 1362152400, 
    1362153000, 1362153600, 1362154200, 1362154800, 1362155400, 1362156000, 
    1362156600, 1362157200, 1362157800, 1362158400, 1362159000, 1362159600, 
    1362160200, 1362160800, 1362161400, 1362162000, 1362162600, 1362163200, 
    1362163800, 1362164400, 1362165000, 1362165600, 1362166200, 1362166800, 
    1362167400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
        MeanWindSpeed = c(7.7, 7.6, 6.7, 7.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.9, 7.3, 
        7.4, 7.8, 7.7, 7.4, 6.5, 6.1, 5.6, 5, 5.8, 6.7, 6.2, 6.6, 
        6.1, 6.4, 5.8, 6.6, 5.9, 6.8, 6.6, 7.1, 7.5, 8, 7.2, 8, 7.2, 
        8.1, 7.7, 7.3, 7.3, 8.1, 7.6, 8.7, 8.1, 9, 8.6, 8.8, 8.8, 
        8.7, 9.1, 9.2, 9.4, 9.8, 9.7, 9.6, 9.7, 10.2, 10.8, 10.9, 
        11.1, 11.6, 11.8, 12.2, 12.5, 12.8, 12.5, 12.3, 11.8, 11.7, 
        11.5, 11.7, 12.1, 12.3, 12.3, 12.9, 13.1, 13.1, 12.6, 12.5, 
        12.6, 12.7, 12.4, 12.3, 12.1, 12.6, 13, 12.7, 13.4, 13.8, 
        13.7, 13.9, 13.8, 13.7, 13.6, 13.7, 13.4, 12.9, 13, 12.6, 
        12.3, 12.3, 12.5, 12.6, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.8, 12.7, 
        12.6, 12.5, 12.6, 12.9, 12.9, 12.8, 12.7, 12.6, 12.8, 12.7, 
        12.6, 12.2, 11.8, 11.4, 11.8, 12.2, 11.7, 11.4, 11.9, 11.3, 
        11.3, 11.1, 11.3, 11.5, 10.6, 9.4, 9.1, 8.5, 8.2, 8, 8, 8.6, 
        8.7, 8.5, 8.4, 8.5, 8.4, 8.5, 7.8, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.1, 7.9, 
        7.4, 7.2, 7, 6.6, 6.7, 6.7, 6.8, 6.6, 5.9, 5.3, 5.6, 5.9, 
        5.3, 4.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.3, 3.7, 1.9, 2.4, 4.5, 4.6, 3, 
        4.7, 3.9, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9, 4.5, 5.2, 4.3, 4.7, 5.3, 5.3, 5.2, 
        5.7, 4.7, 4.9, 5.3, 5.3, 4.7, 5, 4.7, 6.1, 6.2, 6.6, 6.8, 
        8.4, 9.3, 9.5)), .Names = c("TimeStamp", "MeanWindSpeed"), row.names = 2800:3000, class = "data.frame")
```

Within dplyr package, I do the bining on wind speed for less than 10 m/s and above 10 :

```
test = t %>%
     dplyr::mutate(H = hour(TimeStamp) )%>%
     dplyr::mutate(M = month(TimeStamp))%>%
     dplyr::group_by(M,H)%>%
     mutate(wsbin = cut(MeanWindSpeed, breaks = c(0,10,30), labels = c(0,1)))
```

Now I have a column called `wsbin` with `0` and `1` values. How could I define a kind of rolling window which is telling me which data with `wsbin = 0` surrounded by 17 other consecutive data with the wind speed below `10` m/s ???

At the end I would like to have the following table :

[image]

This is telling that in each Hour of each month what is the ratio of flagged data and total data.

Comment: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "hour".`

Comment: @Jimbou I got the same. Try: `library(lubridate)`

Comment: @user5783745 if the number of continuous zeros is more than 18, then the ratio of number of continuous 0 over all 0 and 1 should be calculated for each hour of each month

Comment: In the table above, is that the start or end of the 3 hour period? Like `Hour = 2` and Jan, is that when we begin to see 3 hours of wind speed <= 10 or is that post of seeing three hours of wind speed <= 10?

Comment: As you want intervals of three hours the first column in the picture should be `c("0-3", "4-7",8-11",...)`, right?

Comment: Sorry for me it is completely unclear what you want. Please revise your question!

Comment: It seems like you want to see which hours have full hours of <10 wind speed versus those that do not between different days

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 3 continuous hours

Comment: @Jimbou I have revised the question! Hope is more clear now :(

Comment: @akash87 I have revised the question , I hope is more clear now !

Comment: No it isn't. You only showed graphically what you have already explained by code. But it is still totally unclear how your expected output table looks like as you don't have rows from 0 to 24. Instead you want rolling hour windows or so...

Comment: @Jimbou Is it better now ?! :(

Answer (score 1):

The [tibbletime](https://github.com/business-science/tibbletime) package makes this fairly easy to do if you have complete data. Please note that this method assumes that your data set has some data for EVERY hour. If you don't, you'll need to impute any missing values before using this method.

I've tried to comment the code itself to make it fairly self-explanatory.

```
library(tibbletime)
library(lubridate)

# Turn the sample data into a tibbletime object
tbl <- as_tbl_time(t,TimeStamp)

# Create a function that outputs TRUE if the entire input is less than 10
under10mps <- function(in.vec){
  max(in.vec) < 10
}

# Use the tibbletime package to create a function that rolls on a 3 row window
under10mps3hr <- rollify(under10mps,window = 3)

# Use time based grouping to aggregate times to hourly
tbl2 <- tbl %>%
  # Because rollify works on a 3 row window, we need each hour to be one and only one row.
  collapse_by("hourly",side = "start",clean = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(TimeStamp) %>%
  # Use max windspeed to see to condense data from every 10 minutes to hourly. Other options possible.
  summarise(MeanWindSpeed = max(MeanWindSpeed)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(under10for3 = under10mps3hr(MeanWindSpeed)) %>%
  mutate(month = month(TimeStamp,label = TRUE,abbr = TRUE),
         hour = hour(TimeStamp)) %>%
  group_by(month,hour) %>%
  summarise(prob = sum(under10for3)/length(under10for3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(month,prob)

# # A tibble: 24 x 3
#     hour   Feb   Mar
#     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0    NA     0
# 2     1    NA     0
# 3     2    NA     0
# 4     3    NA     0
# 5     4    NA     0
# 6     5    NA     0
# 7     6    NA     0
# 8     7    NA     0
# 9     8    NA     0
# 10    9    NA     0
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

Note: The sample data only had 1 hour of 1 day of data for each of the months...so with only one hour of input the probability will either be a 0 or a 1 (because it only happened or didn't happen one time). You should get a full range of probabilities if you use a full month of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to identify sequences of three or more consecutive hours below 10m/s, then group by month and take the percentage:

```
counter <- 0
three_or_more <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {

  three_or_more[i] <- 0

  if(test[i, "wsbin"] == 1) { counter <- counter + 1 }

  if(test[i, "wsbin"] == 0) { counter <- 0 }

  if(counter >= 3) {
    three_or_more[(i-2):i] <- 1
  } 

}

test$three_or_more <- three_or_more
test %>% as.data.frame()

# And to get a percent by month:

test %>% group_by(M) %>% summarise(percent_per_month = sum(three_or_more) / n())
```